# Manually increament primary key - Transaction and racing condition

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, race-condition

This may not be a real world issue but is more like a learning topic.

Using PHP, MySQL and PDO, I know all about auto_increment and lastInsertId(). Consider that the primary key has no auto_incerment attribute and we have to use something like `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table` in order to retrieve last id, increment it manually and then `INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (:lastIdPlusOne)`. Wrap whole code in `beginTransaction` and `commit`.

Is this approach safe? If user A and B at the same time load this script what will happens at the end? both transaction will be failed? Or both will be successful (for instance, if the last id was 10, A will insert 11 and B will insert 12)?

Note that since I am a PHP & MySQL developer, therefor I am more interested in MySQL behavior in this case.

Comment: You must ensure that you use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to fetch the `MAX()` in the first (select) query; it will then block until the transaction is committed.  However, this is very poor design and should *not* be used in a production system.

Comment: @eggyal : Thanks, very informative article, I think this is a reliable solution. Unfortunately comments can not be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is @[eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) comment, that I quote here:

> You must ensure that you use a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to fetch the MAX() in the first (select) query; it will then block until the transaction is committed. However, this is very poor design and should not be used in a production system.

Answer (score 0):

If both got the same max, then the one that inserts first will succeed, and other(s) will fail.

To overcome this issue without using using auto_increment fields, you may use a trigger before insert that does the job (new.id=max) i.e. same logic, but in a trigger, so the DB server is the one who controls it.

Not sure though if this is 100% safe in a master-master replication environment in case of a server failure.